# Как исправить ошибку 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'crop'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, numpy

В классе написала такую функцию:

```
def get_cropped(self, i, size):
        self.pictures[i - 1].crop(0, 0, size[0], size[1])
```

При запуске выдаёт ошибку:

> 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'crop'

Я понимаю, что `pictures` типа `numpy.ndarray`.
Но как исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

Текст ошибки достаточно понятный - у объекта типа `numpy.ndarray` отсутствует метод `crop`.

Похоже вам надо что-то вроде:

```
def get_cropped(self, i, size):
    return self.pictures[i - 1][:size[0], :size[1]]
```

[Ссылка на похожий вопрос на англоязычной версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382412/crop-center-portion-of-a-numpy-image)